# How to set a UILabel as a percentage of the width of the UICell with autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm wondering how to set a UILabel's width expressed as a % of the Cell's total width?  I'm using AutoLayout.  Normally I would click on the label and set the EqualsWidth to a parentView and then adjust the multiplier so I set the width as a %  of the parentWidth.  But using InterfaceBuilder that option does not seem to be available within the Cell.  [image]

However I'm wondering maybe it has something to do with setting the preferred Width: I'm using ios8+  and have read that implicit widths are not available for ios8?

[image]

What I am hoping to achieve is that Label 1 and Label 3 are both 15% the width of the Cell and Label 2 has leading and trailing edges pinned to UIImageView and Label 3 that will allow it to grow and shrink depending on the width of the device. 
[image]

Comment: add ration constraint

Comment: Do you mean a Ratio Constraint?  Where you set equal Widths and change the multiplier?  If so this is the problem I'm trying to solve as when I try to set the equalWidths Constraint from the label to another element the option is not available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps you should do to achieve your goal of setting percentage width of any subview inside cell:

1. Add UIView to your cell and pin it to every edge - we have to add custom container view in order to be able to add "Widths equally" pin later on.
2. Add UILabel to previously added UIView container. Lets say we want to add left side label, so add 3 pins to it: left, top, bottom.
3. You can see now that you have error in your constraint setup. So lets fix it and add "Widths equally" pin. Select 2 views in View Controller Scene menu - the container and the label. Go to XcodeMenu/Editor/Pin/ and select "Widths equally". Now you should see no errors in you constraints setup and the label should have same size as the container. (Please note that sometimes you have to refresh frames of your views after setting constraints, so if you see "yellow" warning icon don't be afraid and just click on it).
4. Now if you have all your constraints we need to set actual percentage value. Open tab Size Inspector, click "Edit" title on constraint added in step 3. and change Multiplier value to 0.15 (15%).

Please note that, if you would add label using same technique but for right side, then you would need to set Multiplier value to 6.66 (= 1.00 / 0.15).

Cheers!

[image]

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I was looking for - by adding the UIView and creating the labels and images as children of this view I can use the approach I always use of "Widths Equally" thanks.

Comment: Genius! almost as easy as in android.

Answer (score 0):

You can set width constraint and then create an `IBOutlet` for that in `UITableView` cell and change `constraint.constant` value in `layoutSubView` method of `tableViewCell`

Comment: I'd never have thought of that.  Is that a standard recommended way?  Will give it a shot. thanks

Comment: Yup you can always do that as constant is public property so there is no harm in doing that....