# Xcode constrain UI objects/elements based on percentage

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I just installed Xcode today and I can definitely say these constraints are giving me a really hard time. I haven't even touched code yet because I can't even get the UI to look right.

Basically I have a view set up on the bottom part of the screen:

[image]

Auto layout works correctly for that. My problem is I want to constrain 4 buttons across that view, with each button's width always equal to 1/4 of the view width so that whether the screen is in portrait, landscape, or on iPad, the buttons always fill all the way across the screen. I also want the height to always be 1/5 the height of the view.

There has to be a way to do this... I just can't find it and need some help.

Comment: Make the four buttons have equal width and have zero space between them (for the width part of the question)

Comment: @DavidSkrundz' answer will work. You can also constrain each button's width be equal to the view, and then set a multiplier of `0.25`

Comment: @DavidSkrundz Ah... I was doing that before and it wasn't fitting it, all I had to do was constrain the right-most button to 0 from the right margin and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The height is actually pretty easy. Just constraint the button with the superview by aspect ratio of 1:5.

[image: Aspect ratio in size inspector]

To have the same width you need to have first button constraint to leading edge of the superview, last button to trailing edge and all the buttons need to have equal width constraint, as well as horizontal spacing equal of zero, see [this demo project](https://github.com/libec/StackOverflow/tree/master/07-AspectRatioLayout).

Comment: How do I set a equal heights constraint for the button and superview? I can't select both of them at same time.

Comment: Right click button in the document outline (the views hierarchy on the left side) and drag to superview. Choose equal height and change multiplier afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Setting width: Set equal width constraint between each button and superview, select the constraint and set the multiplier to 0.25.

Setting height: Set equal heights between each button and superview and then set 0.20 a the the multiplier.

You will probably see a 'dashed' orange after you set these up. So you'll need to resize each button until the its gone and you see a blue guidelines (no orange).

Check [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1). Its a bit lengthy, but its worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago I've answered similar question, so you could check this question:

[How to set a UILabel as a percentage of the width of the UICell with autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159228/how-to-set-a-uilabel-as-a-percentage-of-the-width-of-the-uicell-with-autolayout/32160287?noredirect=1#comment52208861_32160287)